# Openfeint properly working on iPhone but not in iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm trying to port an iPhone game app to ipad. In iPhone app open-feint window appear according to screen resolution, yes it working properly.
The process of porting iPhone app to iPad, i create (and target to iPad) new Nib files of each UI Class and i just change the nib name file in **initWithNibName** method and app work fine for iPad that i would like.
Now the problem is that when i launch app on iPad, the first screen open-feint appear with window size 480 X 320 and that screen are totally blank means complete white. But i want to be that screen should be in 1024 X 768 in window size, means it should be open according to iPad size along with all contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out resources folder in framework classes of open-Faint containing ipad files or not. If there is not then add from externally it will work out.